# Using Selenium 3.0.0 on Jenkins throws SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

I am trying to run selenium tests with Selenium 3.0.0 and version of Firefox 48.0.2 on Jenkins (OS : Linux, 64 bit), Gecko Driver for Linux version 0.11.1                                                                                                                 and it throws the following exception:

```
 org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{marionette=true, firefoxOptions=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions@1fdfafd2, browserName=firefox, moz:firefoxOptions=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions@1fdfafd2, version=, platform=ANY}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
  Build info: version: '3.0.0', revision: '350cf60', time: '2016-10-13 10:48:57 -0700'
  System info: host: 'host', ip: 'ip', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.11.0-20-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
  Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:259)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:247)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:242)
    at selenium.utils.Browser.initForJenkinsJob(Browser.java:53)
```

these are the settings which I'm using to initialize the browser:

```
   File pathToLinuxGecko = new File("src/main/resources/geckoDriverLinux/geckodriver");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",pathToLinuxGecko.getPath());
    File pathToBinary = new File(pathToFireFoxOnJenkinsServer);
    FirefoxBinary ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathToBinary);


    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setPreference(FirefoxProfile.ALLOWED_HOSTS_PREFERENCE,  "localhost");

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities= DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);

    driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffBinary,profile,capabilities);

    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I tried locally on Windows with these configurations and it's working:

```
File pathToWindowsGecko = new File("src\\main\\resources\\geckoDriverWindows\\geckodriver.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", pathToWindowsGecko.getPath());
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```